# How to set up and using GeoIP Lite

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I need to be able to use the `MaxMind GeoLite` version to find the users Country, City and `Longitude/Latitude`. The databases are an obvious for which ones I need, apart from the one needed for the longitude/latitude.

Databases needed;

- GeoLite Country
- GeoLite City
- What other one do I need or can the `longitude/latitude` be found via the above databases?

There are multiple versions you can download. Below is a list of ones you can download;

- Binary / gzip
- Binary / xz
- CSV / gzip
- CSV / zip
- CSV / xz

I do not understand what these mean and would like some help to determine which one I will need to download.

Although I'm able to on my 1and1 business account, I have not yet done anything to do with databases. Could anyone give me insights in how I set up a database and upload these files to it?

Lastly, where can I find help on using my new database, reading from it, echoing the users location and whatnot to the page?

Thank you fro your time and any help in advanced.

Best Regards,
Tim

Comment: Unfortunately this is a very very broad question and can't really be addressed here.

Comment: Okay, so ignoring adding this to my database and reading from it, what do I need to download?

Comment: Depends on your system.  You could download any of them. I, personally, would download the CSV/zip and then import it.

Comment: My system? My server is on Linux is that is what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have direct access to the server/command line, you can use the binary format. This offers better performance, but you will need to alter your PHP configuration to install the GeoIP extension or Pecl package. This then gives you access to some handy PHP functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php

Full docs here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

If you don't have access to the server config, you can download the CSV versions and import this into a MySQL DB. You will then have direct access to the data and you can write the relevant queries to produce the results required by your app. If you're using PHP MyAdmin MySQL panel, you can just download the CSV gz or zip and upload/import directly. You will need to create the tables first. Remember to create indexes on the relevant columns.

GeoLite City contains two tables, IP block/City and City Locations (lat/lng). GeoLite Country contains  only IP blocks and country names.

If you don't need IP data, the World Cities Database may be more suitable: http://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities

--EDIT

If you're only concerned with the second file of the geoIP city data, the following SQL will create a table with the necessary columns:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS location;
CREATE TABLE location(
    locId int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    country char(2) NOT NULL,
    region char(2) NOT NULL,
    city varchar(50),
    postalCode char(5) NOT NULL,
    latitude float,
    longitude float,
    dmaCode integer,
    areaCode integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (locId)
);
```

Google is your friend: http://odkq.com/geolitecity

Comment: Presuming you mean under the PHPMyAdmin, I have found a query window I can open and can from there upload files, if this is not what you meant, could you please explain further how I would find out if I have direct access to the server/command line? Best Regards, Tim

Comment: Unless you have a dedicated or virtual server from 1&1 you probably don't have command line access. Stick with the CSVs. Yes use PHPMyAdmin. The following guide (taken from the Maxmind resources page) details what you need to do: http://bartomedia.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/maxmind-geoip-setup-tutorial-using.html

Comment: The first part of this tutorial returns "MySQL said: #1044 - Access denied for user 'dbo458117895'@'%' to database 'geoip'"

Comment: If you're with 1&1, you've probably already created the database in your control panel. So just skip the first part. If you connect to the DB using PHPMyAdmin, you're already "using" the DB, whatever it may be called (not necessarily "geoip").

Comment: Skipping this step seems to get myself back on track with the tutorial. I'll continue but not set this as the answer just yet in case I need further assistance.

Comment: I just downloaded the CSV/GZIP version of the GeoIP Lite City. The tutorial says to find my file, however on the download there is two files int he zip. One is; GeoLiteCity-Blocks.csv, the other is; GeoLiteCity-Location.csv. Which one is the tutorial referring to?

Comment: Open up the CSV's in Excel and have look at the columns. Decide for yourself. The CSV in the tutorial doesn't have lat/lng data. You may need to adapt the queries used in the tutorial slightly, but the principal is exactly the same.

Comment: The GeoLiteCity-Blocks.csv file has three columns in, these are; startIpNum, endIpNum and locId. The GeoLiteCity-Location.csv file has 9 columns which are; locId, country, region, city, postalCode, latitude, longitude, metroCode and areaCode. Presumably I only need the second file, what adjustments do I need to make to be able to load this to my database?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25046/discussion-between-rbaker86-and-tim-marshall)

Comment: I messaged you in chat but I've not heard back from you?

Comment: Okay, so I think I have finally done it... Do you know of any pages which can assist me to add something to my page to test what I have set up so I can ask around my friends to visit my page to see if it's working and whatnot?

Answer (score 0):

### Many Ways to use GeoIP

There are (at least) three approaches to using GeoIP:

- Install GeoIP as a PHP PECL extension (for Apache or NginX), and access it via PHP (there are other languages, this is just one of the more common. Requires root and access to the command line.
- Use an analytics package that uses GeoIP (installed as above), such as the open source [Piwik](https://piwik.org/).
- If you are using something like Wordpress, there is at least one plugin ([GeoIP Detect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/geoip-detect/)) that does not require root.

In general, the database of geographic data is not something you would access directly, but use some kind of application to do lookups (against IP addresses).

Here are some instructions for installing GeoIP Lite database and having it available to PHP. This assumes CentOS/RHEL and Apache

### Installing GeoIP Lite on CentOS/RHEL and Apache

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/GeoIP 
sudo cd /usr/share/GeoIP
sudo wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz
sudo wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
sudo gunzip GeoIP.dat.gz
sudo gunzip GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y geoip geoip-devel
sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
sudo pecl install geoip
sudo nano /etc/php.d/geoip.ini
```

**Add the following to the geoip.ini file**

```
extension=geoip.so
geoip.custom_directory = /usr/share/GeoIP/
```

Restart the web server

### Geographic Variables Available under GeoIP for PHP

The following variables are available via [GeoIP PHP functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php):

- Country
- Region (province, state)
- City
- Post code
- Latitude
- Longitude
- DMA (US/CA)
- Telephone area code (PSTN/NA only)
- Time zone